# How to use Doxygen to document a pointer to a vector of function pointers

Tags: c, doxygen

I am writing my code in C and I have the following situation:

```
typedef struct MyStruct {
   /** Some comment */
   int (*const (*FuncList)[])(void);
} MyList;
```

The Doxygen is returning the following error: Warning: documented symbol `int (*const MyStruct::FuncList' was not declared or defined.

It seens that the Doxygen is not understanding what is a pointer to a vector of function pointers, because if I change to a more simple sentence it works.
I can not change the way to write this sentence because my code must be MISRA compliant.

Comment: More to the point why are you writing code that is difficult to read?

Comment: I do not think that it is so dificult to read. For me, put a lot of typedefs for pointers make the code more difficult to read. In my case, all the information is in one line and it is pretty clear what the element FuncList is. I may be wrong, put I believe that Linux kernel source code, for example, does not allow pointers in typedefs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should help doxygen (and the readers of your code) by using some typedefs, e.g.

```
/** A function pointer */
typedef int (*TFuncPtr)(void);

/** const pointer to an array of TFuncPtr's */
typedef TFuncPtr (*const TFuncList)[];

typedef struct MyStruct {
     /** Some comment */
     TFuncList FuncList;
} MyList;
```

I'm pretty sure MISRA would agree.